How to share DOWNLOAD_DELAY in Scrapyd?
I have a service that randomly sends crawling requests for the same at different times, and the time interval between two crawling requests may be less than DOWNLOAD_DELAY. I want to use Scrapyd to handle crawling requests, and the time interval to send HTTP requests should not be less than DOWNLOAD_DELAY. This may require different scrapyd jobs to share the same DOWNLOAD_DELAY. How to implement that?
I conducted two experiments, the first time only sending one crawl request, and the second time sending two consecutive crawl requests. The way to send a crawl request is through the following command:
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=quotesbot -d spider=toscrape-xpath -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=5 -d setting=RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=False

and all the three elapsed_time_seconds in logs are the same (about 50s).
I've searched on issues, only found #221 met the same question without solution in 2017.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
